# ExtJS 4.2.2: Ext.Direct callback / JSON writer

Tags: json, extjs

I have connected a grid to Ext.Direct, but I am having problems getting it to work properly.

When I create a new record, the new record's ID (which has been generated in PHP) gets returned with the response, but is not saved in the grid's store. So when I try to update this record, I get an error message as it tries to update the record with ID 0.

I believe that I need to set up a JSON Writer on my store's proxy, but I have not succeeded in doing so yet.

Any help getting it to work properly would be greatly appreciated.

Here's what I've done so far:

**The store's model:**

```
Ext.define('Test.model.Post', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    alias: 'model.postmodel',

    requires: [
        'Ext.data.Field',
        'Ext.data.proxy.Direct',
        'Ext.data.reader.Json',
        'Ext.data.writer.Json'
    ],

    idProperty: 'idPost',

    fields: [
        {
            name: 'id',
            type: 'int'
        },
        {
            name: 'idPost',
            type: 'int'
        },
        {
            name: 'achns',
            type: 'string'
        },
        {
            name: 'php_poststring',
            type: 'string'
        },
        {
            name: 'postNo1',
            type: 'int'
        },
        {
            name: 'postNo2',
            type: 'int'
        },
        {
            name: 'postNo3',
            type: 'int'
        },
        {
            name: 'postNo4',
            type: 'int'
        },
        {
            name: 'postNo5',
            type: 'int'
        },
        {
            name: 'postNo6',
            type: 'int'
        },
        {
            name: 'postNo7',
            type: 'int'
        },
        {
            name: 'php_name',
            type: 'string'
        },
        {
            name: 'processCode',
            type: 'string'
        },
        {
            name: 'processText',
            type: 'string'
        },
        {
            name: 'processFreetext',
            type: 'string'
        },
        {
            name: 'postUnit',
            type: 'string'
        },
        {
            name: 'postQuantity',
            type: 'string'
        }
    ],

    proxy: {
        type: 'direct',
        api: {
            create: 'Posts.createRecord',
            read: 'Posts.getResults',
            update: 'Posts.updateRecords',
            destroy: 'Posts.destroyRecord'
        },
        extraParams: {
            licence_id: sessionStorage.licenceid,
            username: sessionStorage.username,
            _c: sessionStorage.control,
            project_id: sessionStorage.projectid
        },
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'data'
        },
        writer: {
            type: 'json',
            writeRecordId: false
        }
    }
});
```

**JSON Posted (createRecord):**

```
{
    "action": "Posts",
    "method": "createRecord",
    "data": [{
        "id": 0,
        "idPost": 0,
        "achns": "I",
        "php_poststring": "",
        "postNo1": 0,
        "postNo2": 0,
        "postNo3": 0,
        "postNo4": 0,
        "postNo5": 0,
        "postNo6": 0,
        "postNo7": 0,
        "php_name": "",
        "processCode": "",
        "processText": "",
        "processFreetext": "",
        "postUnit": "",
        "postQuantity": ""
    }],
    "type": "rpc",
    "tid": 3
}
```

**JSON Response (createRecord):**

```
{
    "type": "rpc",
    "tid": 3,
    "action": "Posts",
    "method": "createRecord",
    "result": [{
        "success": true,
        "message": "Successfully created post",
        "dataroot": [{
            "idPost": 119, // This ID should be updated in the store
            "fkpdHeader": 4,
            "fkpdObject": null,
            "fkpdElement": null,
            "fkndConstructionPart": null,
            "fkpdFloor": null,
            "fkpdCorrection": null,
            "ACHNS": "I",
            "status": 10,
            "descriptionCode": "",
            "ITTBdescription": "",
            "freeTextDescription": "",
            "quantity": 0,
            "unit": "",
            "postNo1": 0,
            "postNo2": 0,
            "postNo3": 0,
            "postNo4": 0,
            "postNo5": 0,
            "postNo6": 0,
            "postNo7": 0
        }]
    }]
}
```

Then when I click the record inserted to edit it and commit it, this happens:

**JSON Posted (updateRecords):**

```
{
    "action": "Posts",
    "method": "updateRecords",
    "data": [{
        "id": 0,
        "idPost": 0, // Not set from previous return
        "achns": "I",
        "php_poststring": "",
        "postNo1": 0,
        "postNo2": 0,
        "postNo3": 0,
        "postNo4": 0,
        "postNo5": 0,
        "postNo6": 0,
        "postNo7": 0,
        "php_name": "",
        "processCode": "",
        "processText": "",
        "processFreetext": "asdads",
        "postUnit": "",
        "postQuantity": ""
    }],
    "type": "rpc",
    "tid": 15
}
```

**Error response (updateRecords):**

> PHP Error - Creating default object from empty value

Because idPost is 0 it is not able to select the record from the database to edit.

**Edit (2014-01-20):**
Added some more code and error information.

Comment: why don't you create an empty array to store returning values?

Comment: I shouldn't have to. Ext.Direct should be able to handle CRUD operations, so there must be something I've set up wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to take a look at the [idProperty](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.data.Model-cfg-idProperty) config for your Model. By default, the Model expects the identifier field to be named "id"; change that to "idPost" and the Store record should be updated properly on response.

Comment: This was how it was before I tried adding a separate id for the Ext.data.Store to use.